# Reseting Windows via command line

Tags: windows-7

My Operating System(windows 8.1) got infected by a virus or a malware. I tried to reset the system back to factory settings via recovery settings. But when I start it there is not a respond. I is just preparing.

So I want to ask if there is a possibility to reset my system back to factory settings via command line.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: -1 what on earth is this talk of resetting the system back to factory settings? What like holding a button for 10 seconds?  are computers running windows getting this small now that they've gone like that? I think you'll find windows still needs to be installed it's not just a reset procedure. Did you insert a recovery cd? Be more clear about the procedure you used to reset to factory settings

Comment: Windows 8.1 or Windows 7? Fix your question or tags using the [edit] button.

Answer (score 1):

Tapping F8 or Shift F8 during boot does not seem to work anymore in windows 8.1.

I think you have to boot from the Windows 8.1 DVD and choose Repair computer, there you will find the options to use system restore, reset your computer or reinstall windows.